# Droppables Not Defined Jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, swap

I am in a situation here, I am trying drag, drop and swap the divs, But an error is occuring,
The li's are to be swapped

```
Uncaught Type error, Cannot read the property of undefined.
```

HTML

```
<ul class="MatchingComponentAnswerRow cl-lg-column-6 cl-md-column-6 cl-sm-column-6 cl-xs-column-6">  
<li class="MatchingComponentRow MatchingComponentAnswer ui-draggable"> <p>hello <b>option</b></p>  </li>  

<li class="MatchingComponentRow MatchingComponentAnswer ui-draggable"> <p>hello option2</p>  </li>  

<li class="MatchingComponentRow MatchingComponentAnswer ui-draggable"> <p>hello option2</p>  </li>  

</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".MatchingComponentAnswerRow  li").draggable({
              appendTo: "body",
              helper: "clone",
              cursor: "move",
              revert: "invalid"
          });

      initDroppable($(".MatchingComponentAnswerRow  li"));
      function initDroppable($elements) {
          $($elements).droppable({
              activeClass: "ui-state-default",
              hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
              accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",

              over: function(event, ui) {
                  var $this = $(this);
              },
              drop: function(event, ui) {
                  var $this = $(this);
                  var li1 = $('<li>' + ui.draggable.text() + '</li>')
                  var linew1 = $(this).after(li1);

                  var li2 = $('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>')
                  var linew2 = $(ui.draggable).after(li2);

                  $(ui.draggable).remove();
                  $(this).remove();

                  initDroppable($(".MatchingComponentAnswerRow  li"));
                  $(".MatchingComponentAnswerRow  li").draggable({
                      appendTo: "body",
                      helper: "clone",
                      cursor: "move",
                      revert: "invalid"
                  });
              }
          });
      }
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/wf6dtxdu/)

Used Dependencies

1.jquery ui 1.8.16,
2.jquery 1.7.2

Please Shed some light, Thanks

Comment: Which line does it occur on? Please mark it in the code.

Comment: $($elements).droppable

Comment: @Krishna make sure your Scripts are loading properly because i've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/wf6dtxdu/) with your code and there is no console error and i can drag and drop the    list items at ease